# Vue Moment add 6 months and use from now

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Is it possible to add 6 months to a date and use from now in a single line of code with Vue Moment

I was thinking something like this:

```
date | moment('add', '6 months', 'DD/MM/YYYY') | moment('from', 'now')
```

Or this

```
date | moment('from', 'now', 'add', '6 months')
```

But these methods didn't work, any ideas? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [chaining](https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment#chaining)

```
date | moment("add", "6 months", "from", "now")
```

[image: Edit keen-babbage-tkcp9]

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as just piping one filter after other one, like in your first try, but without changing the returned format, so the `Date` object remains available to the next filter:

```
{{ date | moment("add", "6 months") | moment("from", "now") }}
```

See it working here:

```js
Vue.use(vueMoment)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      date: new Date(2014, 1, 1)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-moment@4.1.0/dist/vue-moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{ date | moment("add", "6 months") | moment("from", "now") }}</span>
</div>
```